# How to let component.ts load all response before loading template?

Tags: angular

I want to load all the response from functions in component.ts file & then let the template to view that data.

I have 3 functions in my `ngOnInit` function which get me response which I used to load it in template.

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getSong();
        this.getAllSongs();
        this.getProjects();
    }

    // get Latest Song
    getSong() {
        this.amen.getSongs(this.singleSongParam).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.handleSongResponse(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                this.error = error.error.errors;
            }
        );
    }

    getAllSongs() {
        this.amen.getSongs(this.allSongsParam).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.handleSongsResponse(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                this.error = error.error.errors;
            }
        );
    }

    getProjects() {
        this.amen.getProjects(this.projectsParam).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.handleProjectsResponse(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                this.error = error.error.errors;
            }
        );
    }
```

Maybe I use `async/await` but not have any idea how to use it in within subscribe... Please help if there is any method to do that.

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) in .ts and `*ngIf` in template to achieve it.

Try like this:

.ts

```
  loadTemplate: false;

  ngOnInit() {

    const request1 = this.getSong();
    const request2 = this.getAllSongs();
    const request3 = this.getProjects();

    forkJoin([request1, request2, request3]).subscribe(data => {
      this.loadTemplate = true;
    });
  }
```

.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="loadTemplate">
  ...
</ng-container>
```

Comment: It is the best way to achieve this. FYI if you are using forkJoin and any of your api fails then it would be a total failure. For that, you can individually catch and handle accordingly

Comment: @SiddharthPal I agree. Situation like can be handled.

Comment: @AdritaSharma Not working in my case after using forkJoin my component isn't get loaded on page.

Comment: console.log(data[0]), 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Use *ngIf to show the template once you get the response

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forkjoin`. Fork join execute in parallel all request operation and the end join the result. The code is something like this:

```
this.registrationSubscriptionForkJoin = forkJoin([this.service1, this.service2...]).subscribe(response => {
                  this.listresulserivce1 = response[0];
                  this.listresultservice2= response[1];
                }
```

you can call forkjoin in your `ngOnInit` with your method

Comment: But here template will be loaded before getting the response

Comment: no you can use a *ngif where you must specify if (this.listresultserice1!=null" load template. So when the list is calculated the template is showed

Comment: so *ngIf is required without that any way we can achieve

Comment: We can create a component and inject it in the view at run time after getting response from service

Comment: yeah! yes  you must use *ngIf because the template is always loaded after .ts calls all service. So if the list that you use in ngif is not loaded the template is not showed when the list is not empty the template is showed

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve is, Create a field in the component and set it to true once you get all responses. Use this field in template with `*ngIf` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use "Resolver" to do so. You can go through https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-angular-resolver-what-was-the-problem-before-using-resolver-and-why-we-need-it-7502554ab7a3

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Simply using forkJoin and *ngIf**

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jnlret?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**ngIf usage*

```
<div *ngIf="condition">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
```

*forkJoin usage*

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // simulate 3 requests with different delays
    forkJoin(
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request One', 2000),
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request Two', 1000),
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request Three', 3000)
    )
    .subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
      this.propOne = res1;
      this.propTwo = res2;
      this.propThree = res3;
    });
  }
```

**Method 2: Using Resolve Interface**

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ami-ng-data-2?embed=1&file=src/app/multiple-data/multiple-data.component.ts)

Resolve usage

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeroResolver implements Resolve<Hero> {
  constructor(private service: HeroService) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return forkJoin(
       this.service.getHero1(),
       this.service.getHero2(),
       this.service.getHero3(),
    );
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'detail/:id',
        component: HeroDetailComponent,
        resolve: {
          hero: HeroResolver
        }
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

*Reference*

[rxjs - forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

[Angular - *ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

[Angular - Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)